# Remove Double Quotes inside Popover from Dynamic Data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am using Bootstrap Popover to show summary of the Article **dynamically** which means that, this can have **double quotes** (**"**), **single quotes** (**'**), lot of spaces (**`&nbsp;`**) and other **special characters** also. Because of copy/paste content from word, online etc...

Can somebody please help me, how can I remove double quotes from my Popover Content?

**PS:** For demo purpose, I am giving as direct text inside **`data-content`** element. But in real this data will be triggered **Dynamically** from "**`article-description`**" CSS class.

### MY HTML

```
<!-- Working -->
<article class="category-content" data-content="<div class='article-description'>Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet</div>" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with HTML Content</article>

<!-- Not Working -->
<article class="category-content" data-content="<div class='article-description'>Lorem &nbsp;&nsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "Test" Ipsum dolar sit amet</div>" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with Special Characters.. Eg: " (Double Quotes)</article>
```

### MY CSS

```
body{margin:100px auto;text-align:center;}

.category-content{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  background:#eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

### My Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category-content').popover({html:true});
});
```

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtx2ncap/) for more explanation

### :: UPDATE ::

I am able to get the html content without using `data-content` tag now, But still **struglling to remove special characters for dynamic data**.

Can somebody please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest there are better ways of achieving what you're trying to do. Data attributes aren't really intended to contain HTML, and to try to do things this way will make your HTML unreadable (as well as, as you've found, being breakable by quotes).

A better, more robust approach would be to have just the content of the popover (without any HTML tags) in the `data-content` attribute, and use Javascript to create the popover's HTML (`<div class='article-description'></div>`) and insert the content.

Comment: Hey @Nick, Thanks for the suggestion.. as I am not too good at coding it will take some time for me. I will try that... Thanks for your time...